# Найти первый и последний положительные числа массива. найти их сумму. Java

Tags: java, массивы

массив заполняем рандомными числами от -10 до 5.
Надо вывести на экран сумму первого и последнего пложительного.
Java

```
int[] array = new int[30];
int x = 0;
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 16) - 10;
  if (array[i] > 0) {
      System.out.println(array[i]);
  }
}
```

На данный момент смог заполнить рандомными числами и вывести положительные все.
Но как дошло до поиска первого и последнего - зашел в тупик.
Прошу, помощи в нахождении первого и последнего положительных.
Ноль можно считать как за положительное.

Comment: а 0 - это положительный элемент?

Comment: находите положительные числа, первое из них запоминаете в одну переменную, последнее из них - во вторую

Comment: @ metalurgus Тут надо сортировать както?

Comment: Рекомендую использовать термины **положительные** и **неотрицательные**, дабы избежать разночтений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так будет работать:

```
// Инициализация переменных
int[] array = new int[30];

int firstNum=-1;
int lastNum=-1;
int sum;
//Заполнение массива
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 16) - 10;
}

//Поиск первого и последнего положительного числа
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i]>=0){
        // Если первое положительное число еще не найдено
        if (firstNum==-1){
            firstNum=array[i];
        } 
        // Каждый раз обновляем переменную последнего положительного числа
        lastNum=array[i];
    }
}


// Находим сумму
sum=firstNum+lastNum;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я еще смог сам решить задачу используя инверсию массива.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за отзывы. Не судите строго. Учимся.

Решил задачу еще таким вот способом. Я воспользовался инверсией массива.
Интересно узнать мнение опытных ребят.

```
  int [] array = new int [30];
        int k = array.length - 1;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*16)-10;
            if(array[i] > 0){
                x = array[i];
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++){
            int buf = array[i];
            array[i] = array[k];
            array[k] = buf;
            k--;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] > 0){
                y = x + array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(y + "!!!");
```